# open https://xyz.com Basic Auth external website url in Android using PhoneGap View

Tags: android, cordova, https, android-webview, basic-authentication

How can we open external site URL which has basic Auth  in phoneGap View?

```
super.loadUrl("https://google.com"); //it works
super.loadUrl("https://xyz.com"); //this site has Basic Auth, it's not working & it is not giving authentication challenge (popup for credentials)
```

How can we pass the credentials? Right now I am not using any phoneGap features, let me if there is any other way to proceed.

Comment: What do you wish to do? In any case I doubt using HTTP authentication is a good solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Edit your "config.xml" file in the "res" folder, and substitute the following lines in place of what is there

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> 
<access origin="https://xyz.com" /> 
<access origin="https://xyz.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin=".*"/>
```